# Como obtener el puntaje total de una encuesta

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una encuesta, a lo cual cada opción de respuesta tiene un valor de 0 a 4 puntos son 5 opciones de respuesta. Y quisiera obtener solo el resultado total de todas las preguntas, estoy haciendo con Javascript. Quisiera que me ayudarán con ejemplos para poder realizarlo, se los agradecería de antemano.Encontre un ejemplo y trate acomodarlo:
Soy nuevo aprendiendo Javascript

```
<h4>Soy muy educado y creo que la cortesía es muy importante</h4>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="nunca1"> Nunca
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="rara1"> Rara vez 
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="alguna1"> Algunas veces
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="frecuente1"> Frecuentemente
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="siempre1"> Siempre
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <h4>Capto rápidamente lo que no está bien, critico fácilmente</h4>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="nunca2"> Nunca
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="rara2"> Rara vez 
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="alguna2"> Algunas veces
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="frecuente2"> Frecuentemente
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="siempre2"> Siempre
                        </label>
                    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="btnEncuesta">Encuesta</button>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnEncuesta").on("click",index);
});

function encuesta(){
    if($("#nunca1").is(":checked")){
        puntos=0
    }else if($("#rara1").is(":checked")){
        puntos=1
    }else if($("#alguna1").is(":checked")){
        puntos=2
    }else if($("#frecuente1").is(":checked")){
        puntos=3
    }else if($("#siempre1").is(":checked")){
        puntos=4
    }

    if($("#nunca2").is(":checked")){
        puntos=puntos+0
    }else if($("#rara2").is(":checked")){
        puntos=puntos+1
    }else if($("#alguna2").is(":checked")){
        puntos=puntos+2
    }else if($("#frecuente2").is(":checked")){
        puntos=puntos+3
    }else if($("#siempre2").is(":checked")){
        puntos=puntos+4
    }

    if(puntos>=10000){
        $("#buenPuntaje").show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#buenPuntaje").hide();
        },5000);
    }else if(puntos>=100 && puntos<70){
        $("#malPuntaje").show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#malPuntaje").hide();
        },5000);
    }
}
```

Quisiera que me ayudarán con ejemplos para poder realizarlo, se los agradecería de antemano.Encontre un ejemplo y trate acomodarlo: Soy nuevo aprendiendo Javascript

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si nos muestras lo que hiciste podemos ayudarte, pero si no tu pregunta no encaja en el formato, porque todas las respuestas serian correctas.

Comment: ya puse el código, si me podria ayudar se lo agredeceria

Comment: @JousefCasafrancaMayhua Pero lo pusiste como imagen, te agradeceríamos si lo agregas de acuerdo al formato.

Comment: Disculpe, no me debaja anteriormente soy nuevo en la página

Answer (score 0):

1. Primeramente seria mejor que los pongas dentro de la etiqueta `<form></form>` para que así pueda capturar los datos
2. El `button` de tener tipo de `submit`
3. los `radio` se pueden asciar con la etiqueta name, no es necesario recorer cada uno de los objeto buscando que este seleccionado

te dejo el código funcionando, el submit puedes esperarlo directamtente en tu `backend` el `e.preventDefault` es para que no se refresque la página.

seria bueno que leas sobre `form` y `radio`

```js
$(document).on("submit","#encuesta", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      let data = $("#encuesta").serialize();
      console.log(data);
      let preguntas = data.split("&");
      console.log(preguntas);
      let suma = 0;
      preguntas.forEach(item=>{
        let res = item.split("=");
        suma = eval(suma) + eval(res[1]);
      });
      console.log("total de puntos: " + suma);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="encuesta">
    <h4>Soy muy educado y creo que la cortesía es muy importante</h4>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="0" type="radio" name="pregunta1" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="nunca1"> Nunca
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="1" type="radio" name="pregunta1" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="rara1"> Rara vez 
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="2" type="radio" name="pregunta1" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="alguna1"> Algunas veces
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="3" type="radio" name="pregunta1" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="frecuente1"> Frecuentemente
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="4" type="radio" name="pregunta1" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta1" id="siempre1"> Siempre
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <h4>Capto rápidamente lo que no está bien, critico fácilmente</h4>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="0" type="radio" name="pregunta2" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="nunca2"> Nunca
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="1" type="radio" name="pregunta2" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="rara2"> Rara vez 
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="2" type="radio" name="pregunta2" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="alguna2"> Algunas veces
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="3" type="radio" name="pregunta2" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="frecuente2"> Frecuentemente
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input value="4" type="radio" name="pregunta2" class="form-check-input" name="pregunta2" id="siempre2"> Siempre
                            </label>
                        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger"  id="btnEncuesta">Encuesta</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: Gracias, por la ayuda. Voy a leer un poco de documentación de formularios, para entender. También se puede realizar solo en javascript o es necesario aplicar Jquery ?